# Can Gedit plugins bind to the OnSave event?

Tags: python, plugins, gedit, gnome-3

I'm writing a [gedit 3 plugin](http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/PythonPluginHowTo), something similar to [phsilva's PyLint plugin](https://github.com/phsilva/gedit-pylint/), which calls out to an external lint program and highlights lines of code in the current document. My question is, if my plugin has a `run_lint` action is it possible to bind that to the `OnSave` event in gedit? The list of available signals in the documentation I've linked above still has a `FIXME` notice against it and I'm struggling to figure out where in the soup of API documentation the full list can be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, no-one answered this, but I figured it out eventually. There are two steps to this, when a new tab is created in the window that tab contains a document. The document has `loaded` and `saved` signals that can be connected to actions. It's important to remember that each tab has a separate document, each of which needs its own set of signals and handlers.

Here's an outline solution, in case it's useful to others:

```
class FooPlugin(GObject.Object, Gedit.WindowActivatable):

    __gtype_name__ = 'Foo'
    ...

    def do_activate(self):
        self._add_ui()
        self.window.connect('tab-added', self.on_tab_added)
        ...
        return

    def on_tab_added(self, window, tab, data=None):
        doc = tab.get_document()
        doc.connect('saved', self.on_document_saved)
        doc.connect('loaded', self.on_document_loaded)
        return

    def on_document_loaded(self, document, data=None):
        # do something here...
        return

    def on_document_saved(self, document, data=None):
        # do something here...
        return
```